# Binomial Expansion Find: $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k} 2^k $

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, combinations

Find:
$\sum_{k=0}^n  \binom{n}{k}2^k$

So I know how to find the coefficients of binomial expansions but I’m not sure how to do this type of problem where I just find the summation.

The example in the book is $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} 4^k $ and the answer is $5^n$

Thank you for any and all help.

Comment: I’m sorry I’m still new to this and using mathjax as well thank you again.

Comment: Use the binomial theorem with $(1+2)^n$. In the example in the book, didn't they expand $(1+4)^n$?

Comment: By example I meant just that there was another question and the back of the book had the answer $5^n$

Comment: Both can be solved that way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}2^k =\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}2^k 1^{n-k}=(2+1)^n$$ By Binomial theorem.

$$(a+b)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}a^kb^{n-k}$$

Comment: So all the question is looking for is an answer of  the expansion $(1+2)^n$ or $3^n$?

Comment: Given the expansion, find the compact form. Yes, just like $5^n$ is the answer to the other question, $3^n$ is the answer to this question. You are being tested on the ability to recognize the formula.

Comment: Ah I understand now. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5):

Hint:

rewrite is as $$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}2^k1^{n-k}$$
Any recognition?